たい and ほしい used together

In the top panel the character wonder if something bad or sad happened to his friend who recently has been making a sad face.
The he says the it's the kind of mood that  "聞きたいけど聞いてほしくなさそう"
How should one take this? Is the talking about himself? How do たい and ほしい work together here?
"The mod you want to ask but you don't want to be asked"?

It is (私は)聞きたいけど(彼は)聞いてほしくなさそう

You can tell from the そう in なさそう that the person wanting something, or the subject of ほしい, is not the speaker. In this context, it must be the friend he is talking about.

ほしくなさそう
[the friend] doesn’t seem to want

The verb in [V て-form]-ほしい is always an action by someone other than the one wanting, or the subject of ほしい.

聞いてほしくなさそう
[the friend] doesn’t seem to want [other people] to hear/ask

Actually, the subject of the 聞く in 聞きたい is context-dependent. Since this たい is used inside a subordinate clause (ending with けど), it could be the friend that wants to hear or ask something, but it doesn’t seem to make sense in this context. It must be the speaker.

聞きたいけど聞いてほしくなさそう
although [I] want to hear/ask, [the friend] doesn’t seem to want [other people (or specifically me)] to hear/ask

